# Flex shield moist protection against fungus?

Tags: wood, hardwood-floor, moisture

Contractors are currently replacing a wooden floor which had been bowing, and repainting a wall. Both were damaged as a result of a leaking air conditioning pipe in the wall.

I’ve expressed a concern that if they just paint over it, or fix the wooden floor, within a matter of days, that there is a serious chance of fungi developing. I was told that they are going to put a layer of “flex shield moist protection”, which should do away with my concern.

My gut feel says this protection layer is to keep moisture out of concrete, not prevent fungi from developing. My gut feel says they should open up the wood, sand the wall down to bare concrete, and let both surfaces dry for a while. And then put it back in place.

Would appreciate comments.

Comment: When I have specified how a contractor was to do something and *I* didn't know how the job *should be* done, the collaboration has not gone well.

Comment: Yeah, it’s even more strained as I’m a tenant and not the owner. But if I’m worried about fungi, I won’t live comfortably.

Comment: Really it is up to the landlord. I associate Flex Shield with high intensity TV advertising.